# How to bypass slcli cancel confirmation challenge

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, cancellation

is there anyway to cancel a virtual node without being prompted for a confirmation?

Here is what I mean:

```
slcli vs cancel 33379977
```

This action cannot be undone! Type **33379977** or press Enter to abort:

In some cases, slcli does support challenge question answer on the command line.  For example:

```
slcli vs create **-y** vs create --hostname="fubar" ....
```

However, for cancel, not sure how to go about.

`slcli vs cancel 33379977` < hostid.file*  also does not work.

Does anyone know how to go about suppressing confirmation challenge?

thanks in advance.

K

Answer (score 0):

“The proper request on SLCLI to cancel a Virtual Server requires an [option] parameter set as **-y** in order
to confirm all prompt actions, for example:

```
slcli -y vs cancel 33379977
```

Regarding your request example to create a VS, it is also has not been set properly according to your example:

*slcli vs create **-y** vs create --hostname="fubar" ....*

Please refer to the following request to order a Virtual Server correctly:

```
slcli -y vs create --hostname="fubar" --domain="foo.com"
--cpu=4 --memory=4 --datacenter="dal05" --os="UBUNTU_LATEST"
```

I tested using [SoftLayer API Python Client](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python) last version: **5.2.6**

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much.  I think I must have tried all combination except the one you specified.  I confirm that your solution works!